# How to use XFGloss on WinPhone 8.1 Xamarin Portable Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.winphone

I'm making one portable xamarin application, and i'm using [XFGloss](https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss). Everything is working fine on Android and iOS, but on WinPhone 8.1 my BackGroud Gradiant still black.

My page has:

```
<xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
  <xfg:Gradient Rotation="150">
      <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#305E70" StepPercentage="0" />
      <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#305E70" StepPercentage="1" />
  </xfg:Gradient>
</xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
```

On, Android and iOS i should initilize xfgloss, like this:

-Android

```
XFGloss.Droid.Library.Init(this, bundle);
```

-iOS

```
XFGloss.iOS.Library.Init();
```

And i dont found how to init XFGloss on WinPhone, even know if have to init this.

[image]

How to make this works on WinPhone?

Comment: XFGloss only targets Android and iOS.

Comment: I dont have found an way to user XFGloss on windows phone, them I discontinued the project to windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

XFGloss has no support for Windows. I guess it would never support WP8, but sometimes it may get support for UWP. At least [there is issue](https://github.com/tbaggett/xfgloss/issues/1) for that